# Error(14,7): PLS-00049: bad bind variable

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have tried everything but Oracle 11g Express Edition gives me this error for the procedure.

> Error(14,7): PLS-00049: bad bind variable

Here is my procedure

```
create or replace procedure select_member_data
AS
 memberdata      MEMBER%rowtype;
 member_ID    MEMBER.MEMBER_ID%TYPE;
 first_name   MEMBER.FIRST_NAME%TYPE;
 last_name    MEMBER.LAST_NAME%TYPE;
 address      MEMBER.ADDRESS%TYPE;
 total_rows number(2);
BEGIN
 SELECT MEMBER_ID,first_name,last_name,address
 INTO :memberdata
 FROM MEMBER where member_id= 1 ;
 IF sql%notfound THEN  
  dbms_output.put_line('no records fetched');  
 ELSIF sql%found THEN     
  dbms_output.put_line( total_rows ||' fetched');  
 END IF;   
END;
```

here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE MEMBER (
MEMBER_ID  INT PRIMARY KEY,
LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
FIRST_NAME varchar2(25),
ADDRESS varchar2(100),
CITY varchar2(30),
PHONE varchar2(15),
JOIN_DATE  date  DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL  
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing:

```
 SELECT MEMBER_ID,first_name,last_name,address
 INTO :memberdata
 ...
```

but `memberdata` is a local PL/SQL variable, not a bind variable, so it should just be:

```
 SELECT MEMBER_ID,first_name,last_name,address
 INTO memberdata
 ...
```

You also aren't fetching enough columns into your `%rowtype` variable. You table has seven columns, so your `memberdata` record variable has seven fields as well; but your query is only selecting four columns - which isn't enough. (Slightly confusingly, this is reported as too many values, rather than not enough values).

You can list all of the column names, but this is a rare occasion where it may be better (or at least justifiable) to use `*`:

```
 SELECT *
 INTO memberdata
 ...
```

Or as you have the other variables defined already you could do:

```
 SELECT MEMBER_ID,first_name,last_name,address
 INTO member_ID, first_name, last_name, address
 ...
```

although I'd stongly recommend you don't have variable names that are the same as column names; it's common to prefix local variable with something to identify them, e.g. `l_member_id`.

Your logic is flawed though. If your query doesn't get exactly one row then a no-data-found or too-many-rows exception will be thrown. (You can't have more than one because of the primary key here, but you could find none). The `sql%notfound` check won't be reached.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your answer but if I change it to memberdata then I'm getting too many values error

Comment: @varnit - I just added a bit about that, you have to select all of the columns (or equivalent expressions/values) - the number of columns in your query has to match the number of fields in the record you're selecting into.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude I'm messing my head around this from hours

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) you find something on what to do when someone answers you.

Comment: @AlexPoole In PL/SQL, placeholders can also be used for output variables.

Comment: @sql_dummy -you mean as the `into` target? Then yes, but it only makes sense in an anonymous block. That wasn’t what was happening here, or what the OP was trying to do

Comment: Okay just mentioning if declared `:rec_var table_x%rowtype;` then `select * into :rec_var from table_x where rownum=1;` is valid.

Comment: And i realized as you said may be it could make sense only in anonymous block.  But why would is raise a compile error in case of stored procedure? Could you please answer it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956011/bad-bind-variable-why-bind-does-not-happen-in-below-case/47956078#47956078)