# bad bind variable : Why bind does not happen inside stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, bind

Why does the following code fail to compile with below error. I tried to run the block three times each time with different input `a`, `1`, and `NULL`.

```
Name    Null Type         
------- ---- ------------ 
col_nam      VARCHAR2(20)
```

Compile log:

```
Error: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'x'
```

Code:

```
create or replace function ret_bool return boolean is
num_var number;
begin
  select col_nam into num_var from ex04011601 where col_nam=:x; //statement 1
  return true;
end;
/
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense for a bind variable to appear in the body of a function because the language has no mechanism for supplying it with a value. How would you use it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in X as a parameter to your function:

```
create or replace function ret_bool( X IN VARCHAR2)
 return boolean is
num_var number;
begin
  select col_nam into num_var from ex04011601 where col_nam= X; 
  return true;
end;
```

Comment: I am not trying to workout the block. My doubt here is why couldn't I use a bind variable here.

Comment: I explained why.  You are creating a pl/sql function.  That function runs on the database.  It has no clue about external variable values.

Comment: So i guess even if use bind variable at procedure specification `create or replace procedure proc(:n1 in out number) is` it still would have any clue of reference right?

Comment: @sql_dummy I'm not sure what `procedure proc(:n1 in out number)` would do if that syntax existed. Where you have `:n1`, there should be the name of a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Because in this case the host variables cannot be referenced anywhere in the definition of a PL/SQL procedure.

> ....For each placeholder in the SQL statement or PL/SQL block, you must
>   call an OCI routine that binds the address of a variable in your
>   program to the placeholder...

Here during the compilation the place holder does not have a variable (allocated with memory) to whose address it can get binded.

Answer (score 0):

> "i guess even if use bind variable at procedure specification `procedure proc(:n1 in out number)...`"

At some point the user has to provide **an actual value**. That is the place to use a bind variable.

Let's take your function and use a parameter as PL/SQL:

```
create or replace function ret_bool (p_arg in number)
return boolean is
    num_var number;
begin
    select col_nam into num_var 
    from ex04011601
    where col_nam= p_arg;
    return true;
end;
/
```

The correct way to use a bind variable is when you **call the function**:

```
EXEC SQL EXECUTE 
BEGIN 
  :x := ret_bool(:n);
  ...
```